# Back4App - Parse Query not returning any PFObects in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, back4app

In this scenario back4app initialised successfully, user login and signup also working, but when I am fetching all user list by using the below code, its returning blank array, without any error, there are three users in the User class in back4app. Can anyone help?

```html
 let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
            query.findObjectsInBackground { (result, err) in
                 print(result)
                 print(err)
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User class was created by the Parse server. And that is the reason why is it a protected class. To reach these kinds of classes you need to use underscore character before the class name.

I mean don't use **User** for className, use it: **_User**

```
   // let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
   let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
   query.findObjectsInBackground { (result, err) in
         print(result)
         print(err)
   }
```